# div_for: NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying an ror tutorial and I came across the following line of code:

index.html.erb:

```
<%= render :partial => @players %>
```

_player.html.erb:

```
<% div_for player do %>
<%= player.FNAME %> <%= player.SURNAME %>
<% end %>
```

players_controller.rb:

```
def index
    @players = Player.all(:order => "FNAME")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
end
```

I want to modify the index.html.erb so that there is no need for a partial but it's not working properly.

Please see code below.

index.html.erb:

```
<% div_for @players do %>
<%= @player.FNAME %> <%= @player.SURNAME %>
<% end %>
```

NoMethodError in Players#index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a direct translation of your code:

```
<% @players.each do |player| %>
  <% div_for player do %>
    <%= player.FNAME %> <%= player.SURNAME %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The `render :partial` given a collection (`@players` this case) would walk through the collection one by one and render the partial for you.

But rendering a collection also gives you a counter and spacer template too.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, div_for will is looking for an id in order to make:

```
 <div id="the_id">
```

Because you pass an array, and not an object anymore, it's lost.

You should use content_tag for your purpose.

See doc here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
    <% @players.each do |player| %>
    <p><%= player.FNAME %></p>
    <p><%= player.SURNAME %></p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

FYI it's a good idea to keep that stuff in the partial.

Comment: Why is it a good idea to keep that stuff in a partial? It's not ALWAYS a good idea to have stuff in partials. If this the only place in his application where he iterates over players like that, then (IMO) there is no benefit in using a partial.

Comment: A partial that is only used in one place does not have any R to D.

Comment: yes, but it's still looks better + how do you know that in future you dont will be need to use it again?